# Toolbar spacing issue using Android Design Support Library

Tags: android, xml, androiddesignsupport, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appcompat

While following [liuguangqiang's sample](https://github.com/liuguangqiang/AndroidDesignSupportSample) and even [Chris Bane's cheesesquare](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) samples for Android Design support library, there seems to be an issue in the Toolbar spacing, like in the image.

[image: toolbar menu overlapping]

Here is my activity.xml code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="192dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/header"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/scrollableview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_add"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

As you can see, I've followed Chris Bane's sample very closely. This issue however exists only on Lollipop, while it works perfectly fine on pre Lollipop.

Anyone experiencing the same issue, or know of a possible fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it is a known issue which will be fixed in a future release. Please check this [link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175240)

In the meantime in the above link is proposed a workaround that may help. You can check it.

Comment: Thanks for that @TheoK
I've found a similar issue here as well: [link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175069)
Hope it gets resolved in the next update!

Answer (score 6):

Remove android:fitsSystemWindows from coordinator layout.

Comment: @Suleiman19 Add this to your theme `<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>`

Comment: I've already added that @Michael. If you go through those two git links I've originally mentioned, my activity, xml and styles are exactly the same as those. Yet still experiencing that issue.

I found this issue:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175069
Maybe its a bug in the Design support library itself?

Comment: This worked for me in Support Library 23.1. Thanks @MichaelPaleo .

Comment: Thanks its worked.. This bug they need to fix in 23.2.0. In this version another bug also there for recylerView nestedscrolling.. it will not give smooth. You need to nestedscrollingEnabled false in onCreate